# PMD Failure: ILogin:73 Rule:ConstantsInInterface Priority:3 Avoid constants in interfaces

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle, pmd, cpd

Can someone tell me how to exclude some interfaces from PMD analysis using maven. I am getting the below exception while making the maven build.

PMD Failure:  ILogin$RetrieveLoginInfo_:4 Rule:ConstantsInInterface Priority:3 Avoid constants in interfaces. Interfaces define types, constants are implementation details better placed in classes or enums. See Effective Java, item 19..
[

I have added exclude-pmd.properties in pom's properties. This is my entry in pom.xml properties.

```
<pmd.excludeFromFailureFile>${project.basedir}/src/etc/exclude-pmd.properties</pmd.excludeFromFailureFile>
```

exclude-pmd.properties  entry:

```
com.login.ILogin=ConstantsInInterface Priority:3 Avoid constants in interfaces.
```

Interface:

```
public interface ILogin {
    interface RetrieveLoginInfo_ {
    int STATUS=0
    }
    }
```

But maven is not exluding ILogin interface from PMD analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the structure of your `exclude-pmd.properties` is incorrect. As per https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/violation-exclusions.html

You are expected to use the rule name alone as the value (comma-separated), so in this case it should read:

```xml
com.login.ILogin=ConstantsInInterface
```

That being said, I think you are expecting a different behavior from this property.

This will simply avoid the `pmd:check` task from failing if the only violation reported is that one on that file. It will not ignore the file from analysis. It's meant mostly as a way to incrementally enable PMD on a legacy project.

You should probably use a different approach for the use case you describe.

1. You can simply suppress this warning in the source code, following https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.15.0/pmd_userdocs_suppressing_warnings.html
2. You can actually ignore the file from analysis (for all rules!) through a custom ruleset, following https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.15.0/pmd_userdocs_making_rulesets.html#filtering-the-processed-files

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. This approach is working for me. I can't add  a customer rule set to exclude that class. I am using a parent dependency where all rules are declared there. So I don't have a control over it.

Comment: @Sunil glad it worked. You should consider the suppression in that case. Also, please consider marking this response as correct for future reference.